# Disable Pytest in PyCharm

Tags: unit-testing, pycharm, pytest

If I have a file beginning with "test_", PyCharm tries to run this with PyTest.  I want to run it normally (as a regular Python script).  How can I do this?

**Edit** See Milo's answer below.  If for some reason that does not work for you, as A. Romeau pointed out, there is a way to do this on a per-file basis:

1. For a given test file that you want to run normally:

- Run the file... note that it runs under py.test or some other testing framework.
- Click on the drop-down box on the top-right that says something like "py.test in test_something.py".
- Click "Edit Configurations".  This will open a window with "Python" and "Python tests" as options on the left.  You'll notice you're in the "Python tests" section.
- Copy the file path in the "Target:" field.
- Click the red "-" in the top left, which will remove that test configuration.
- Now, click the green "+", select "Python", and paste the file path you copied in the "Script:" field.
- Press "OK".  Your test file will now run as an ordinary script.

2. Edit your setup.cfg file in pytest (with some option that I don't know right now) so that it doesn't "discover" your test (I have not tried this).

Neither solution is good.  1 is inconvenient because you need to go through a big mutli-click and process for each file you might want to run like this.  2 is inconvenient because it interferes with you running pytest normally, from console.

JetBrains: Please for the love of God just add an option to disable automatic unittesting.  It is very annoying because the output of pytest/UnitTest is not nearly as helpful as the output of the regular interpreter when trying to track down bugs in tests (no links to the failing line, can't easily run given function alone, etc).

A PyCharm "issue" has been opened [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19687).

Comment: Please add my request as well to plea to JetBrains to fix this.

Comment: perhaps this is what you need: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000413650-Disable-automatic-test-function

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Disable Pytest for you project**

1. Open the **Settings/Preferences | Tools | Python Integrated Tools** settings dialog as described in Choosing Your Testing Framework.
2. In the **Default test runner** field select **Unittests**.
3. Click OK to save the settings.

[image]

Comment: @Peter I recommend you shift the green check mark to this answer

Comment: Good call - yes I just tried this and it worked.  Thanks Milo

Answer (score 6):

You can either create a run configuration for that specific file, under Run/Edit Configurations, or you can change the test discovery settings for py.test, so files starting with test_* are not considered test files by default.

More information here:

http://pytest.org/2.2.4/example/pythoncollection.html

Comment: Thanks.  But neither solution is great for me.  See edit.

Comment: Changing the run configurations is, unfortunately, the best way.  On top-right, go to the drop-down list, then Edit Configurations > Remove the Test config (press "-"), Add a config under Python, with the full path to the script in the "Script:" field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and just want to run the file you have to go to the top of the file and click `Run | Run`

details:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000413650-Disable-automatic-test-function

or manually create a run.

Or rename your functions without starting the word tests.

Annoying!