# Why does Pycharm start a test when I name a function test_

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Why does PyCharm suddenly wants to start a test?

My script is named `1_selection_sort.py` And I'm trying to call the function `test_selection_sort`, and I'm just running with `<current file>` (Added in 2022.2.2 I assume).

I'm pretty sure this worked 24/10/2022 (Version 2022.2.2 and maybe 2022.2.3, but in 2022.2.4 it's no longer working).

Could someone please tell me when and why this was changed? Or maybe I did something wrong during installing?

My file is NOT named according to this naming scheme (https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery):

```
In those directories, search for test_*.py 
or *_test.py files, imported by their test
package name.
```

```
"""
Schrijf een functie selection_sort dat een lijst in dalende volgorde sorteert m.b.v. selection sort.
"""


def selection_sort(lijst):
    for i in range(len(lijst)):
        for j, number in enumerate(lijst):
            if number < lijst[i]:
                lijst[j] = lijst[i]
                lijst[i] = number
    return lijst


def test_selection_sort(lijst, check):
    print(lijst)
    result = selection_sort(lijst)
    print(result)
    print(check)
    assert result == check


print("Begin controle selection_sort")
test_selection_sort([1, 3, 45, 32, 65, 34], [65, 45, 34, 32, 3, 1])
test_selection_sort([1], [1])
test_selection_sort([54, 29, 12, 92, 2, 100], [100, 92, 54, 29, 12, 2])
test_selection_sort([], [])
print("Controle selection_sort succesvol")
```

Output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:/Users/r0944584/AppData/Local/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.4/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path "C:\Users\r0944584\Downloads\skeletons(4)\skeletons\1_selection_sort.py" 
Testing started at 14:13 ...
Launching pytest with arguments C:\Users\r0944584\Downloads\skeletons(4)\skeletons\1_selection_sort.py --no-header --no-summary -q in C:\Users\r0944584\Downloads\skeletons(4)\skeletons

============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

1_selection_sort.py::test_selection_sort ERROR                           [100%]
test setup failed
file C:\Users\r0944584\Downloads\skeletons(4)\skeletons\1_selection_sort.py, line 15
  def test_selection_sort(lijst, check):
E       fixture 'lijst' not found
>       available fixtures: anyio_backend, anyio_backend_name, anyio_backend_options, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

C:\Users\r0944584\Downloads\skeletons(4)\skeletons\1_selection_sort.py:15



========================= 1 warning, 1 error in 0.01s =========================

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Because you prefixed a function name with `test`. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out already, buy why does it do this?

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery

Comment: @bad_coder, the weird thing is that my file is NOT named according to that naming scheme.

Comment: You don't explain how you are running the tests.

Comment: I'm just running the <current file> configuration, this worked a few versions ago. I don't understand why it's doing this.

Comment: @Nineteendo we don't know what your run configuration looks like, so we don't know how you're running pytest.

Comment: I've not touched the run configuration, I'm just running <current file> on version 2022.2.4.

Comment: @Nineteendo Well, then that's not the right way of running pytest in PyCharm. There are 2 main ways, one is using the terminal (recommended) the other is using a dedicated *run configuration* (also recommended). But in both cases you need to do some extensive setup for pytest to find your files. Otherwise check pytest's CLI options to run a single module.

Comment: @bad_coder, but the thing is, I don't want to run PyTest, just the current file. Do you have any idea what could be set up incorrectly that causes this weird behaviour?

Comment: @Nineteendo the solution for just running the code is easy, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66193923). The message PyCharm was giving you is that the IDE was using its own pytest launcher - something you usually don't want, and from the question it wasn't clear what your intended fix is. But if you want something easy just set the run configurations manually to your liking (that's something you always have to know how to do).

Comment: @bad_coder, that wasn't really helful, but you made me think of disabling pytest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59203776/13454049 that fixes my issue, yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to disable Pytest following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59203776/13454049

> Disable Pytest for you project
> Open the Settings/Preferences | Tools | Python Integrated Tools settings dialog as described in Choosing Your Testing Framework.
> In the Default test runner field select Unittests.
> Click OK to save the settings.